# ASP.NET Site Search Engine

Tags: asp.net, search-engine

On my ASP.NET web application, there is a search form which redirects the user to a page such as:

```
/Search.aspx?q=query_text
```

On this page, I want to display search results from the site pages.

What is the best way of doing this? Would I be better trying to develop a search engine by storing page content in the database, or is there an easy way of pulling this from google?

If I use google is there a way of getting the results in RSS format with URLs and titles so its easy to implement into the application?

Comment: You need CMS, try dotnetnuke CMS which is free. There are many other free cms according to your need is available.

Answer (score 1):

if your data are coming from the database then you search should be from the database for sure !

but if you have static pages on your website then you can replace them by create a table for the content of the static web pages and then you can add your query to search on them.

Comment: Sorry I meant I didn't know whether to store an Index in the database, or use Google API for this.

Comment: okay, google API is a fast good solution for your web application .

but I preferred to store your data in the database.